# Problem with Aligning of buttons in Stack View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im having hard time getting this functionality and Im beginner in iOS Development:
[image]

I need the buttons sizes and shapes (I got 6 in my storyboard) to not lose size or shape when I add them to a stack view. My target is to set an equal distance between them so the UI doesnt look weird.

I tried various Alignment, Distribution, Content Mode and I finally gave up at this:

[image]

First image's width from left is increased automatically (which I dont want) and the other 5 button's size is not exactly square (I want buttons with equal width and height)

What am I doing wrong? Please help I cant achieve this since about 24 hours!

Comment: Do you want your 6 buttons to stretch the full width of the screen (with maybe a little spacing on the sides)? AND you want them to be square (1:1 ratio)? Or, do you want 6 buttons at maybe a fixed size of `40x40`, with "standard" spacing between them, and have that `(6 * 40) + (5 * spacing)` centered horizontally in the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How you set your stack view properties and constraints, and the button constraints, will depend on exactly what you want as a result.

Take a look at these image - first one includes the `Editor -> Canvas -> Bounds Rectangles`:

[image]

[image]

In all three, Button 1 has a 1:1 Ratio constraint.

---

The Top stack view is constrained Top (40) and Leading and Trailing at 16-pts from the sides. Stack view properties are:

- Alignment: Fill
- Distribution: Fill Equally
- Spacing: Standard

So, the stack view width is the width of the view, minus 32 (16-pts on each side). The stack view automatically gives each button the same width - `Fill Equally` - and the 1:1 constraint on the first button sets its Height equal to its Width (square), and the rest of the buttons follow suit.

---

For the Middle example, the stack view is constrained Top (40) and CenterX. Stack view properties are:

- Alignment: Fill
- Distribution: Fill Equally
- Spacing: Standard

The only additional constraint is Button 1 has a Width constraint of `40`. So all 6 buttons are `40 x 40`, standard spacing between them, and the stack view is centered horizontally.

---

For the Bottom example, the stack view is constrained Top (40) and Leading and Trailing at 16-pts from the sides. Stack view properties are:

- Alignment: Fill
- Distribution: Equal Spacing
- Spacing: Standard

In addition, Button 1 has a width constraint of `40`, and Buttons 2 thru 6 all have `Width = Button1.width`.

So the stack view width is the width of the view, minus 32 (16-pts on each side). Each button is `40 x 40` (again, the `1:1` ratio on Button 1 keeps them square), and the stack view set the spacing to fill out the width.

---

You'll want to keep in mind how that will change on different device sizes.

For example, here's how that looks (with NO changes to constraints or properties) when we rotate the device:

[image]

---

Here is how the structure looks in Storyboard:

[image]

and here's the source to the Storyboard so you can examine / play with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="Stack View standard spacing" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="o2J-7j-Hec">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="qIB-4e-obb" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Aak-ib-U1S">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacingType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="DHB-rx-egj" userLabel="FitWidthStack">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="40" width="343" height="50.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8Ue-Xm-LQi">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50.5" height="50.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="8Ue-Xm-LQi" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="IvC-Jh-rdd"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <state key="normal" title="1"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="R14-hZ-UbE">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="58.5" y="0.0" width="50.5" height="50.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="2"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="syB-R1-vN7">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="117" y="0.0" width="50.5" height="50.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="3"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="f1X-gj-ygM">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="175.5" y="0.0" width="50.5" height="50.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="4"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fK2-cI-wo3">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="234" y="0.0" width="50.5" height="50.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="5"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="MQX-O8-Tgu">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="292.5" y="0.0" width="50.5" height="50.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="6"/>
                                    </button>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacingType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="D9y-7o-SD4" userLabel="CenterXStack">
                                <rect key="frame" x="47.5" y="130.5" width="280" height="40"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PVs-vi-HFL">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="40" id="2tP-1p-WIh"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="PVs-vi-HFL" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="iph-ol-vl6"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <state key="normal" title="1"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Zam-9o-U4q">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="48" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="2"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Fdn-MX-Ivu">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="96" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="3"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="dhX-aw-ohs">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="144" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="4"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nJO-xF-B3Y">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="192" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="5"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JZ6-Lc-yzW">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="240" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="6"/>
                                    </button>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="equalSpacing" spacingType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2eO-xS-xt7" userLabel="EqualSpacingStack">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="210.5" width="343" height="40"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="5OX-TX-zzE">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="40" id="FaE-ZG-cnh"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="5OX-TX-zzE" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="yEH-j6-Ikc"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <state key="normal" title="1"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vy5-wT-KZg">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="60.5" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="2"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xIu-el-0yH">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="121" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="3"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Suq-hc-eDl">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="182" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="4"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hP2-U2-MNf">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="242.5" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="5"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kb1-3H-bP7">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="303" y="0.0" width="40" height="40"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="6"/>
                                    </button>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="kb1-3H-bP7" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="5OX-TX-zzE" secondAttribute="width" id="AMt-Sm-61b"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Suq-hc-eDl" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="5OX-TX-zzE" secondAttribute="width" id="Exj-gK-x8q"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="hP2-U2-MNf" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="5OX-TX-zzE" secondAttribute="width" id="mKn-cn-wIQ"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="vy5-wT-KZg" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="5OX-TX-zzE" secondAttribute="width" id="rNn-Ua-n1n"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="xIu-el-0yH" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="5OX-TX-zzE" secondAttribute="width" id="vJn-JR-owY"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="aBq-0M-X4Y" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="DHB-rx-egj" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="OcR-HJ-Rx7"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="D9y-7o-SD4" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="DHB-rx-egj" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="40" id="b2A-fw-h9B"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="aBq-0M-X4Y" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2eO-xS-xt7" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="jTT-lY-SsV"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="D9y-7o-SD4" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Aak-ib-U1S" secondAttribute="centerX" id="ozD-RG-kNP"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="2eO-xS-xt7" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="D9y-7o-SD4" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="40" id="pUh-eN-YIc"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="2eO-xS-xt7" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="aBq-0M-X4Y" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="r55-1B-nXd"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="DHB-rx-egj" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="aBq-0M-X4Y" secondAttribute="top" constant="40" id="rIG-gC-m8w"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="DHB-rx-egj" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="aBq-0M-X4Y" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="zLt-pT-M4r"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="aBq-0M-X4Y"/>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="FGl-dQ-rQ5"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="QHx-YZ-Q6S" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="268" y="170.46476761619192"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks for enlightening me! Thats a great answer and kudos for putting so much effort to help me out! Love you!

Answer (score 0):

Select the `stackView` and change the `Distribution` property to be `Equal Spacing` as shown in the image below:

[image: Equal spacing distribution]

Embed each button in a `UIView` to be able to set the width and height. Then make sure to constrain each button to it's containing view, by adding `leading, trailing, top and bottom` constraints. Afterwards, you can specify a width and height for the buttons. Make sure to specify the `width` for each button. The `height` however needs to only be set to one button, but there's no issue if you specify a height for all the buttons, provided the heights are the same. I've attached a screenshot for clarity.

[image: Buttons nested withing uiviews and with proper constraints]

Comment: This is what happens when I do that: https://prnt.sc/trq2bh 

I just now noticed that you added the stack view inside a "view" why did you do that? In what cases is it necessary?

Comment: Make sure you have set constraints to the stackview (top, leading, trailing, bottom/height), and don't add any constraints to the buttons

Comment: I want those button's sizes (both width and height to be same as what I set before adding those buttons to the stack view) Stack view change the aspect ratio width and height and I dont want that. What to do?

Comment: The size of the buttons before I added them to the stack view was 30 x 30, I dont want them to lose this size or aspect ratio. What to do?

Comment: For each button, put it inside a `UIView`. Then you can add constraints to the buttons but none to the `containing views`

Comment: Now this happens: https://prnt.sc/trqb1a 

What constraints should I add exactly?

Comment: That's because the buttons are missing some constraints (`leading, trailing, top, bottom`)

Comment: 1. The `containing view` should not have any constraints. 2. The buttons should have the following constraints: `width and height of 30` and `leading, trailing, top, bottom` constraint to the `containing views`. Use `0 (zero)` as the constraints constant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218976/discussion-between-sylvan-d-ash-and-millie-hudson).

Comment: I tried few variations and the most sensible constraints to add was Horizontally Center in Container and Vertically Center in container for buttons. I got my desired layout by doing this: https://prnt.sc/trr0t7 But now I have another problem, now my buttons doesnt have pressing effect when I launch the app in the simulator. I cloned one of those buttons and put it in the center of the screen to test and this button have the pressing effect when I press it. Now Im confused again.